# Node.js route sends to the incorrect controller

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Problem:** When I call this route `/topproducts` it enters in the `orders_get_order` function and not in the `orders_most_ordered_products`. This is very strange I can't understand why it enters in the wrong function.

**The console error message:**

```
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "topproducts" at path "_id" for model "Order"',
    name: 'CastError',
    stringValue: '"topproducts"',
    kind: 'ObjectId',
    value: 'topproducts',
    path: '_id',
    reason: undefined,
    model: Model { Order }
```

My route.js

```
router.get("/topproducts", checkAuth, OrdersController.orders_most_ordered_products);
```

My controller order.js

```
exports.orders_most_ordered_products = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let order = await order_service.get_most_ordered_products();
    if ('error' in order){
      res.status(order['status']).json(order)
    }else{
      res.status(200).json(order)
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log("most orders")
    console.log(err)
    //res.status(500).json(fatal_error_status);
  }
};

//get uma order
exports.orders_get_order = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let order = await order_service.get(req.params.orderId);
    if ('error' in order){
      res.status(order['status']).json(order)
    }else{
      res.status(200).json(order)
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log("get orders")
    console.log(err)
    //res.status(500).json(fatal_error_status);
  }
};
```

And then it sends to the service order.js

```
exports.orders_most_ordered_products = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let order = await order_service.get_most_ordered_products();
    if ('error' in order){
      res.status(order['status']).json(order)
    }else{
      res.status(200).json(order)
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log("most orders")
    console.log(err)
  }
};

exports.orders_get_order = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    let order = await order_service.get(req.params.orderId);
    if ('error' in order){
      res.status(order['status']).json(order)
    }else{
      res.status(200).json(order)
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log("get orders")
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Comment: Usually when this happens is because there is another route, registered before this one, that matches.
Try to verify the order of the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the order of the routes, the route that takes an Id as a parameter was first so the server though I was calling that one.

```
router.get("/topproducts", checkAuth, OrdersController.orders_most_ordered_products);

router.get("/:orderId", checkAuth, OrdersController.orders_get_order);
```

Comment: Yes I was gonna answer you the same! :D